# Querying more than 1 table in a single query via JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, syntax

I cannot quiet get using the JOIN clause around my head, even after I have ready multiple posts on the topic.

Here is my problem:
At the moment I have 2 tables.

Users Table:

```
ID | Username | Password
1  |   Micky  |   123
2  |   Mouse  |   145
```

Questions Table:

```
Question ID| Question_Title   | Question      | Rating | Category ID | User ID |
    1      | Meaning of Life? | Same as Title |  100   |      2      |    1    |
    2      | Foo is love?     | Same as Above |   95   |      4      |    2    |
```

Now I simply want to run a query which will find a match in the title and the find out which user ID corresponds to that question and then get the name of the user, as well as the Question Title, Question and Rating then print them out.

So far I have:

```
"SELECT Question_Title, Question, Rating FROM Questions WHERE Question_Title LIKE  '%$Term%'";
```

This works as in it will get me the Question Title, Question and Rating from the table wherever it finds a match but how would I use JOIN so that it will also get me the Username from the Users table?

Also this is just early implementation I will in the future have a lot more tables that will require similar query so I need to understand how this works.

P.S: I know their are plenty of examples like this but I had trouble understanding them so if one of you kind souls could break it down and explain I would be grateful.

Comment: this is hands down the best explanation of joins out there - http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Dinesh Taking a look now, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
    u.username
    q.Question_Title, 
    q.Question, 
    q.Rating 
    FROM Questions q
    join Users u on u.id = q.userid
    WHERE q.Question_Title LIKE  '%$Term%'";
```

Comment: Thanks, This one worked like a charm, however can I trouble you for a little explanation what "w" and "u" do and how they got their?

Comment: @ShatteredPheonix, The q and u are Table alias. We join two or tables using its Primary key and foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.* from a join b on a.id=b.a_id join c on c.b_id = b.id
```

in your case something like this:

```
SELECT Question_Title, Question, Rating,user.* FROM Questions join User on user_id=id WHERE Question_Title LIKE  '%$Term%'";
```

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.. :)

Comment: Ok after trying this one it does work, however it was printing out twice as many rows for some reason. SO my array would print out each row twice.

Comment: just add an group by user_id :P